# Show tutorial view controller ONCE in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, appdelegate, rootviewcontroller

I am fairly new to programming and am struggling with being able to programmatically show a "tutorial" view controller only once when the users open the app.

I have referenced previous questions here to get code but it does not seem to work on my app.
From these pictures below, you can see the setup of my storyboard and my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function code.

ALSO, I tried programmatically loading my tutorial view controller every time I launch the app (so I removed the user defaults code) and that does not work either. When I did this, I simply get a black screen.

Am I missing something in my code or is there a setting I am missing to check?
I am using Xcode Ver 11.5 and swift 5.

code used:

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if defaults.object(forKey: "FirstTime") == nil {
        defaults.set("No", forKey:"FirstTime")
        defaults.synchronize()
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialViewController") as! TutorialViewController
        
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SivPW.png)

[appDelegateCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmgrR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if this is what you want.

```
     if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if defaults.object(forKey: "FirstTime") == nil {
            defaults.set("No", forKey:"FirstTime")
            window.rootViewController = TutorialViewController()
        } else {
            window.rootViewController = OtherViewController()
        }
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: You are awesome! When I tried your code, I put it in the scene function (under scene delegate) and it showed a black screen. To fix that I added the code    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialViewController") as? TutorialViewController and then set the window.rootViewController = viewController and it finally worked! Thanks again!

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that I'm using xib to push a new controller. That's why it's a bit different from your code. Still, glad it's what you need.